# How to filter views block depending on field value?

Tags: 7, views

I have two content types "Company" and "Contact". The content type "Contact" have a Entity reference field referencing "Company", it also has a text field called field_country.

Company1--->Contact1 (UK)

Company1--->Contact2 (UK)

Company1--->Contact3 (USA)

- Contact1,2,3 are different nodes of type "Contact" referencing a
  "Company".
- UK, USA is value of field (field_country) in type
  "Contact" of different nodes.

Currently I have a views block showing on type "Contact", listing all the nodes referencing the parent "Company". Now i want to filter the view based on the field value of field_country. **In other words i want a list of nodes referencing the parent node from the same country as the current node.**

*i.e on Contact1 and Contact2 views block i want to show:*

- Contacts1 (UK)
- Contacts2 (UK)

*on Contacts3 views block:*

- Contacts3 (USA)

So how to accomplish it using Drupal 7 and views 3?

Comment: Have you tried adding a filter based on the value of field_country?

Comment: The field_country has different values for different nodes. I have tried adding filter as a well as contextual filter but i am unable to make it work dynamically.